# JUnit 4 test for overloaded constructor with composite class

Tags: java, junit, composition

If I am writing a JUnit 4 test for an overloaded constructor of a composite class, say Dog is one class and Tail is another where tail has fields string colour and string shape , this is the method signature Dog(String, Tail), what do I put where the '?' is ?

```
@Test
public void testDog(){
  Dog d1 = new Dog ("Sparky", ? );
  assertEquals("Sparky", d1.getName());
  //assertEquals
}
```

if it is something like `Dog d1 = new Dog ("Sparky", t1 );` then what would I put on second assertEquals? its default constructor values or its overloaded constructor values?

or would I have to create a new instance of Tail with the values?

Comment: try testing always only one layer at a time. for "composite" classes check out Mockito, for easy creation of mocks

Comment: Yes, you create a `Tail` object or pass `null` to the constructor (if it makes sense to provide `null`).

Comment: @Progman and then would the best way to test this be with assertSame instead of assertEquals? if I create t1("black","bushy");  then have assertSame(t1,d1.getTail) ? Thanks

Comment: @Laura Check the javadoc for `assertSame()` and `assertEquals()` and decide yourself what you want to check. Usually you want to use `assertEquals()` since this will use the `equals()` method to check the objects instead of `==`. You only use `==` on objects when you clearly know what that check means and what you want to do.